# How to retrieve multiple objects records in the Batch Apex execute method?

Tags: apex, soql, batch

I need to wrap records from Opportunity, Account, Quote, User objects. I need help with Batch Apex **execute** method. how to retrieve those records and wrap them with the wrapper class on **execute** method.

In the execute method I don't get data, just get the Id.

```
global class MyBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
         String query = 'SELECT Id, Account.Name,CreatedBy.LastName,SyncedQuote.Name, Description, Amount, CloseDate, Type FROM Opportunity limit 10';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> records){
        //Just get the Id's nothing else.
        // Need help from records how to retrieved informations. 
    }    

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        // execute any post-processing operations
    }    
}
```

**Batch Apex SOQL**

```
SELECT 
Id, 
Account.Name,
CreatedBy.LastName,
SyncedQuote.Name,
Description,
Amount,
CloseDate,
Type
FROM Opportunity limit 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `execute` method parameter of the `records` is `List<sObject>` which is not a concrete SObject, but a general Sobject. In order, to get field values from `Opportunity`, you can cast `SObject` to `Opportunity` and use dot notation to get field value.

```
public class MyBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Account.Name, CreatedBy.LastName, SyncedQuote.Name, Description, Amount, CloseDate, Type FROM Opportunity LIMIT 10]);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> records){
        for(SObject record :records){
            Opportunity opp = (Opportunity) record;
            System.debug('Account.Name: ' + opp.Account.Name);
            System.debug('CreatedBy.LastName: ' + opp.CreatedBy.LastName);
        }
    }    

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    }    
}
```

---

I've also done the following improvements to your code:

- `public` access modifier instead of the `global`. `global` is used in a managed package to make elements accessible outside of the namespace
- move SOQL query from string to SOQL expression. Allows to detect problems with query during compilation

Comment: Also, in general, you could change `records` as the parameter to just `List<Opportunity>`.

Comment: Just one minor comment: `global` access does do what you said, but actually makes the class **visible across namespace boundaries**. You must use `global`, for example, to expose a subscriber class so it can be instantiated and invoked within an installed managed package too. Similarly for exposing a class from one managed package to another managed package, etc.